# android scrollview set android:scrollbars="none",the scrollview doesn't work

Tags: android, scrollview

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
</ScrollView>
```

I set android:scrollbars="none",the scrollview doesn't work

Comment: Please refer this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbars

Answer (score 5):

You can get the instance of ScrollView using findViewById and disable the scrollbars programatically, refer this [`Blog`](http://r00tsecurity.org/forums/topic/12052-android-hide-scrollbar-in-scrollview/)

```
  ScrollView sView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);
  sView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
  sView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```