# Scrollview doesnot appears after putting it in xml file in android

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

Inside my xml file i put a scroll view. But it doesn't shows in my program. I was confused because i checked for any color problems. Here is my xml file, can anyone specifies the reason it doesn't shown at there?

Please note: some characters from textview and edittext are removed due to character limitation by stack overflow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rtop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"             
            android:background="@drawable/top_transperant_bg" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/imageViewlogo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_home"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Your Home"
                android:textColor="#c1c1c1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"                    
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
          <RelativeLayout
            android:background="@drawable/bg_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rtop"
            android:layout_above="@+id/Rbottom"                 
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
           >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/s1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/midle"             
            android:scrollbars="none"    
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
              <LinearLayout 
                   android:id="@+id/Rcentre"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                     android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rela"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
                         />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText1"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/Edittextwidth"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/Edittextheight"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:capitalize="words"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal" >
                    </EditText>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:maxLines="6"
                        android:text="Contact Person" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText2"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/Edittextwidth"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/Edittextheight"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/regtextfieldborder"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:capitalize="words"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Home Email" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText4"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/Edittextwidth"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/Edittextheight"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/regtextfieldborder"
                        android:editable="false"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Home Phone Number" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText9"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/Edittextwidth"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/Edittextheight"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText10"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/Edittextwidth"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:lines="6"
                        android:maxLines="10"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine" 
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText10"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editText10"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Residence Type" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/Edittextwidth"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText10"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/combo_bx"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:popupBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        />
                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Share my email address with other homeowners"
                        android:textColor="#FF0000"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText9"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editText9"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Show my info to other residents"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Share my contact with other homeowners"
                        android:textColor="#FF0000"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
                        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:text="Next>>"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView5"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:text="Vehicle Status  "
                            android:textColor="#c1c1c1" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view1"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/radioButton2"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

                            android:text=" Yes" />

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/view1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="#c1c1c1" />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/firstvehicle"
                                android:layout_width="282dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:visibility="gone" >

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                      android:layout_width="50dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Make    "
                                        android:textColor="#c1c1c1" />

                                    <EditText
                                        android:id="@+id/vehiclemake1"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                        android:background="@drawable/regtextfieldborder"
                                        android:ems="9"
                                        android:padding="5dp"
                                         android:inputType="textCapSentences" 
                                           android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal" 

                                        android:singleLine="true" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/textView2more1"
                                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                        android:background="@drawable/more_button"
                                        android:clickable="true"
                                        android:visibility="gone"
                                        android:gravity="center" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                       android:layout_width="50dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Model   "
                                        android:textColor="#c1c1c1" />

                                    <EditText
                                        android:id="@+id/vehiclemodel1"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                        android:background="@drawable/regtextfieldborder"
                                        android:ems="9"
                                          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                         android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal" 
                                          android:inputType="textCapSentences" 
                                           android:padding="5dp"

                                        android:singleLine="true" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="License"
                                        android:textColor="#c1c1c1" />

                                    <EditText
                                        android:id="@+id/vehiclenumber1"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                        android:background="@drawable/regtextfieldborder"
                                        android:ems="9"
                                        android:padding="5dp"
                                         android:inputType="textCapWords" 
                                          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                          android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal" 

                                        android:singleLine="true" />
                                </LinearLayout>
                                <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/linearcolour"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView

                   android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:textColor="#c1c1c1"
                    android:text="Color     " />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/colour"

                      android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ems="9" />
                 <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/textView2more"
                                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                        android:background="@drawable/more_button"
                                        android:clickable="true"
                                        android:gravity="center" />

            </LinearLayout>

                                <View
                                    android:id="@+id/view1"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                    android:background="#c1c1c1" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayouts"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/firstvehicle"
                                android:orientation="vertical" >
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/button1"
                                android:layout_width="100dp"
                                android:layout_height="35dp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/mainLinearLayouts"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/buttoncolour"
                                android:onClick="submit"
                                android:text="Submit"
                                android:visibility="gone"
                                android:textColor="#c1c1c1" />
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

                            android:text=" No" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                        android:text="Address" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/regtextfieldborder"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                        android:lines="5"
                        android:maxLines="6"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal" >

                    </EditText>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="#c1c1c1"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/profile_image" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/midle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonsubmit"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttoncolour"
                android:gravity="center"
                 android:textColor="#c1c1c1"
                android:text="Submit"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Rbottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the output of such a complicated layout?

Comment: @Apurva the scrollbar doesnot shows the output ...it is hidden somewhere.....

Answer (score 0):

You used Some illegal character with XML

Also You have used some Empty views. That will not display proper output. and Each and every view must have height and width attribute in it. You missed in some.

I corrected some errors. This Might can help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rtop"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff6700" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rtop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#80ff6700" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageViewlogo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Your Home"
        android:textColor="#c1c1c1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Rbottom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rtop"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#20ff6700"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/s1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Rcentre"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rela"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText3" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:capitalize="words"
                android:textSize="10sp" >
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:maxLines="6"
                android:text="Contact Person" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="80sp"
                android:layout_height="20sp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#ff6700"
                android:capitalize="words"
                android:ems="10"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Home Email" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#ff6700"
                android:editable="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Home Phone Number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText9"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView9" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:lines="6"
                android:maxLines="10"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText10"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText10"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Residence Type" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText10"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#ff6700"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:popupBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Share my email address with other homeowners"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText9"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText9"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Show my info to other residents"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Share my contact with other homeowners"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Next>>"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="Vehicle Status  "
                    android:textColor="#c1c1c1" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view1"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/radioButton2"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
                    android:text=" Yes" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#c1c1c1" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/firstvehicle"
                        android:layout_width="282dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:visibility="gone" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Make    "
                                android:textColor="#c1c1c1" />

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/vehiclemake1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="35dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="#ff6700"
                                android:ems="9"
                                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:textSize="10sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView2more1"
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:background="#ff6700"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:visibility="gone" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Model   "
                                android:textColor="#c1c1c1" />

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/vehiclemodel1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="35dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="#ff6700"
                                android:ems="9"
                                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:textSize="10sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="License"
                                android:textColor="#c1c1c1" />

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/vehiclenumber1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="35dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="#ff6700"
                                android:ems="9"
                                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:textSize="10sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/linearcolour"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Color     "
                                android:textColor="#c1c1c1" />

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/colour"
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ems="9"
                                android:singleLine="true" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView2more"
                                android:layout_width="25dp"
                                android:layout_height="25dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:background="#ff6700"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:gravity="center" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/view1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="#c1c1c1" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayouts"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/firstvehicle"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/mainLinearLayouts"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="#ff6700"
                        android:onClick="submit"
                        android:text="Submit"
                        android:textColor="#c1c1c1"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:text=" No" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
                android:text="Address" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#ff6700"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                android:lines="5"
                android:maxLines="6"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="10sp" >
            </EditText>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#c1c1c1"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/midle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonsubmit"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="#ff6700"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textColor="#c1c1c1" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Rbottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your replay..i removed those attributes due to charecter limitation by stackoverflow....i specified it earlier in my question...If any misunderstanding happens i am really sorry....my problem is that scrollbar is hidden whereever i am needed.....i already put scrollview inside my layout

Comment: try this. I change your drawable with colors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793834/android-scrollview-set-androidscrollbars-none-the-scrollview-doesnt-work

Reffered the above link and got the solution....